# Error-handling #ifdefs for AFNetworking requests

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking, error-handling, macros

I am using AFNetworking 1.4.3 to send and receive network messages in iOS. My application works slightly differently in DEBUG and RELEASE mode, so I need to use `#ifdef` clauses. How can I simplify the following fragments without making these macros:

- ```
  #ifdef DEBUG
          if (failure) failure([NSError fromDict:responseObject]);
  #else
          if (failure) failure([NSError networkError]);
  #endif
  ```
- ```
  #ifdef DEBUG
          if (failure) failure(error);
  #else
          if (failure) failure([NSError networkError]);
  #endif
  ```

Whole code:

```
@implementation ELHTTPClient

- (instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self) {
        __weak ELHTTPClient *weakSelf = self;
        [self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
        [self setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
            [weakSelf.delegate httpClient:weakSelf connectionStateChanged:status];
        }];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)myPostPath:(NSString *)path parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))success failure:(ELErrorBlock)failure {
    [self postPath:path parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if ([responseObject isResponseValid]) {
            if (success) success(responseObject);
        }
        else {
#ifdef DEBUG
            if (failure) failure([NSError fromDict:responseObject]);
#else
            if (failure) failure([NSError networkError]);
#endif
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
//        [self.delegate httpClient:self networkError:error];
//        NSLog(@"Network error. Operation: %@, \n Error: %@", operation, error);
#ifdef DEBUG
        if (failure) failure(error);
#else
        if (failure) failure([NSError networkError]);
#endif
    }];
}

- (void)myGetPath:(NSString *)path parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
          success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *dict))success
          failure:(ELErrorBlock)failure {
    [self getPath:path parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if ([responseObject isResponseValid]) {
            if (success) success(responseObject);
        }
        else {
#ifdef DEBUG
            if (failure) failure([NSError fromDict:responseObject]);
#else
            if (failure) failure([NSError networkError]);
#endif
//            NSError *error = [self.serializer errorFromDictionary:responseObject];
//            [self.delegate httpClient:self requestFailedError:error];
        }
    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        if (failure) failure(error);
#else
        if (failure) failure([NSError networkError]);
#endif
    }];
}

@end
```

My implementation of NSError category:

```
@implementation NSError (My)

+ (NSError *)networkError {
    NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [userInfo setValue:@"Some problems with connection to network. Please try again later." forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];//FIXME: add localized string.
    return [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Connection error" code:1024 userInfo:userInfo];
}

+ (NSError *)fromDict:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    NSString *errorDesc = dict[@"description"];
    errorDesc = errorDesc ? : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dictionary: \n%@", dict];
    NSMutableDictionary* details = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    details[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = errorDesc;
    NSNumber *errorCodeNum = dict[@"errorCode"];
    return [NSError errorWithDomain:@"world" code:[errorCodeNum intValue] userInfo:details];
}
@end
```

Comment: Is `+[NSError fromDict:]` defined in AFNetworking or where does not come from?

Comment: No, it's my own implementation. See edited content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put `ifdef DEBUG` inside the `failure` method, so it's handled in one place only.

```
(void) failure(id response, NSError error) {

#ifdef DEBUG

#else

#endif

}
```